# Sticky footer pattern working in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css

The sticky footer pattern ensures that the footer sticks to the bottom of the viewport unless the non-footer content is tall enough in which case it is pushed  below the bottom of the viewport.

The following application of this pattern works for Chrome and Opera but not Firefox. Am I missing anything?

```css
     #container {
       min-height:100%;
       position:relative;
     }

     #non-footer {
       padding-left: 1em;
       padding-right: 1em;
       padding-bottom: 150px; /* 100px + 50px (#footer::height + #footer::margin-top) */
     }

     #footer {
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       margin: 50px 0 0 0 ;
       height: 100px;
       background: brown;
     }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div id='container'>
      <div id='non-footer'>
        <h1>Sticky footer pattern</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean libero ex, tempus quis dolor at, consectetur lobortis leo. Etiam faucibus velit non turpis euismod lacinia. Vestibulum lobortis neque sed mi vestibulum, sit amet venenatis nulla auctor. Aenean porttitor sed purus id ornare. Mauris sed fermentum sem, id dapibus dolor. Nullam ullamcorper ut sem in consectetur. Quisque accumsan mauris vitae mi faucibus, sed blandit libero scelerisque. Donec vitae luctus metus, non fermentum elit. Duis purus ante, tempor vestibulum facilisis id, iaculis sed eros. Maecenas condimentum tortor suscipit aliquam feugiat. Sed sed enim egestas, venenatis ex at, pharetra nibh. Nullam faucibus tincidunt erat in mollis. Nulla a nunc lacus. Proin in pellentesque lorem.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id='footer'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Surprisingly, even though it works from Chrome (when I place the HTML in a file) it's not displayed properly in the Stack Overflow's HTML pen facility in full page mode — even though I'm still using Chrome. What is observed instead is that the footer rises from the bottom of the viewport. This is the exact same failure mode that is observed under Firefox.

Comment: Just a quick observation, removing position: relative from #container fixes it in the code snippet... not sure how it would do in a browser by itself.

Comment: @wpalmes not a good way as the footer will overlap the content.

Comment: Good point... that's what happens when I don't really take the time to look at it.  Your answer works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh) unit coupled with [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)...

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh; /* make the container at least the height of the viewport */
  display: flex; /* use flexbox */
  flex-direction: column; /* use a vertical flex layout */
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1; /* expand to fill remaining container height */
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean libero ex, tempus quis dolor at, consectetur lobortis leo. Etiam faucibus velit non turpis euismod lacinia. Vestibulum lobortis neque sed mi vestibulum, sit amet venenatis nulla auctor. Aenean
    porttitor sed purus id ornare. Mauris sed fermentum sem, id dapibus dolor. Nullam ullamcorper ut sem in consectetur. Quisque accumsan mauris vitae mi faucibus, sed blandit libero scelerisque. Donec vitae luctus metus, non fermentum elit. Duis purus
    ante, tempor vestibulum facilisis id, iaculis sed eros. Maecenas condimentum tortor suscipit aliquam feugiat. Sed sed enim egestas, venenatis ex at, pharetra nibh. Nullam faucibus tincidunt erat in mollis. Nulla a nunc lacus. Proin in pellentesque
    lorem.
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working but only if the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of `body` are 0. If they aren't, then part of the footer is cropped and a vertical address bar appears. I assumed that in that case (i.e. of non-zero margins of the `body` element) I had to do: `min-height: calc(100vh - 2em)` (or whatever twice the vertical margin of `body` is) but I didn't get good results with that neither with Chrome, nor with Firefox. Am accepting this answer for now.

Comment: instead of doing `.content {flex-grow: 1}` you can also do `.container {justify-content: space-between}` (with a slightly different effect, but still yielding a sticky footer)

Answer (score 0):

Set your html, body height to 100%

```
html, body
{
  height:100%;
}
```

```css
html, body
{
  height:100%;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#non-footer {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  /* 100px + 50px (#footer::height + #footer::margin-top) */
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='container'>
    <div id='non-footer'>
      <h1>Sticky footer pattern</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean libero ex, tempus quis dolor at, consectetur lobortis leo. Etiam faucibus velit non turpis euismod lacinia. Vestibulum lobortis neque sed mi vestibulum, sit amet venenatis nulla auctor. Aenean
        porttitor sed purus id ornare. Mauris sed fermentum sem, id dapibus dolor. Nullam ullamcorper ut sem in consectetur. Quisque accumsan mauris vitae mi faucibus, sed blandit libero scelerisque. Donec vitae luctus metus, non fermentum elit. Duis
        purus ante, tempor vestibulum facilisis id, iaculis sed eros. Maecenas condimentum tortor suscipit aliquam feugiat. Sed sed enim egestas, venenatis ex at, pharetra nibh. Nullam faucibus tincidunt erat in mollis. Nulla a nunc lacus. Proin in pellentesque
        lorem.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Pointers**: [Sticky Footer - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

Comment: This is better but now the bottom of the footer lies outside of the viewport.

Comment: (the above comment applies in full-screen mode)

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46552933/274677) I ended up adding the following mozilla-specific fix:

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
   html {
     height: 100%;
   }
   body {
     height: 95%;
   }
 }
```

`95%` is necessary as if `100%` is specified, then the bottom of the footer gets cropped in Firefox (no idea why).

```css
     @-moz-document url-prefix() {
       html {
         height: 100%;
       }
       body {
         height: 95%;
       }
     }

     #container {
       min-height:100%;
       position:relative;
     }

     #non-footer {
       padding-left: 1em;
       padding-right: 1em;
       padding-bottom: 150px; /* 100px + 50px (#footer::height + #footer::margin-top) */
     }

     #footer {
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       margin: 50px 0 0 0 ;
       height: 100px;
       background: brown;
     }
```

```html
    <div id='container'>
      <div id='non-footer'>
        <h1>Sticky footer pattern</h1>
        <p>
          <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/q/46552641/274677'>SO question</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean libero ex, tempus quis dolor at, consectetur lobortis leo. Etiam faucibus velit non turpis euismod lacinia. Vestibulum lobortis neque sed mi vestibulum, sit amet venenatis nulla auctor. Aenean porttitor sed purus id ornare. Mauris sed fermentum sem, id dapibus dolor. Nullam ullamcorper ut sem in consectetur. Quisque accumsan mauris vitae mi faucibus, sed blandit libero scelerisque. Donec vitae luctus metus, non fermentum elit. Duis purus ante, tempor vestibulum facilisis id, iaculis sed eros. Maecenas condimentum tortor suscipit aliquam feugiat. Sed sed enim egestas, venenatis ex at, pharetra nibh. Nullam faucibus tincidunt erat in mollis. Nulla a nunc lacus. Proin in pellentesque lorem.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id='footer'>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This works in Firefox as well but not as a Stack Overflow HTML/CSS snippet (when in full screen mode).

Comment: This cannot possibly be the solution since it would imply Firefox does not properly apply height which is not true.

Comment: @Rob I can't argue with your reasoning but experimental results trump reasoning.

Comment: Not to go on and on about this but if my calculator says 6+4=0, and that's the result I want, I don't think I would continue to use that calculator.